# Problem after upgrading ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, ubuntu-10.04

After upgradation of my system from ubuntu 9.10 to ubuntu 10.04. I am not able to find minimize and maximize buttons of any opened window

**EDIT**
My problem is that my minimize maximize buttons are not appearing
**metacity --replace**  is solving my problem but untill that terminal is open.. How to make it parmanent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new defaults for Ubuntu `10.04` seem to have the buttons on the left (as suggested in other answers here). To restore things back, there are a couple of references on this [Ubuntuforums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1465461).

1. Change your theme
2. Restore them back with [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com)
3. (also) HowToGeek [Metacity solution](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13535/move-window-buttons-back-to-the-right-in-ubuntu-10.04/)

If you have lost the buttons it might have something to with customized settings in your installation.

Comment: another decent how-to link (from the forums thread) is http://motersho.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/08/fix-minimizemaximizeclose-button-order-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/ ... but i like the HowToGeek explanation best

Comment: My problem is that my minimize maximize buttons are not appearing
metacity --replace is solving my problem but untill that terminal is open.. How to make it parmanent...

Answer (score 0):

Disable compiz altogether. Right-click on your desktop and search for Visual Effects. Select none. (Or uninstall Compiz packages). Metacity --replace does nothing else just replacing Compiz with Metacity the default Gnome wm. (Also, you can go to System-> Sessions (it should be around there, search for "Session" or "Sessions" there), and add `metacity --replace` as an autostarting application. :) (You will get used to workarounds with Linux don't worry. :))

Comment: not option like system_>sessions

Comment: ? It is a standard and installed on EVERY Gnome. Check it in every menu then, it HAVE TO be there. :/